# Update field after every 2 minutes via firebase functions for all users in database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am looking for a solution to update a field in my entire database in every 2 minutes with the help of firebase functions. Is it possible ?

Ex:- I have users collection which contains adsCount field of 0. I want this field to be updated after every 2 mintues with the increment of 1. with one single firebase function.

```
exports.adsCount = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 2 minutes').onRun(async context => {
    //add 1 adcount add after every 2 minutes 
    return admin.firestore().collection('users')

})
```

I am using pubsub for this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  You will have to write the code to do what you want in your function.

Comment: Thanks for quick response! All i want to know is that how to write code in order to target entire users collection without doc id. As far as i know to update a field we need to pass the doc id. but here i want to write a function which update field for me automatically to all the users present in the current firestore database.

Comment: There is plenty of documentation online.  Start there, then post back here if there is something that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: I tried everything but nothing works :(

Comment: @DougStevenson please help me out in this. I am struggling with this since yesterday.

Comment: OMG!! how can be someone so dumb! :P sorry sometimes my mind stops working or due to sleepless nights. That was just a normal array querysnapshot. and thanks @DougStevenson for helping me. If you didn't pushed me to find more into this. i couldn't be able to recognize my fault.